# Formatting numbers in csv.DictWriter

Tags: python, csv, formatting

I am writing a csv file from a `dict` with a `DictWriter`. Any floating point number is written with a period. I would like to format the numbers with a comma, so that Excel recognizes the numbers correctly. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can convert the numbers to strings first and then use `str.replace` to replace `.`s with `,`s.

Comment: Thanks :-) that actually did it for me.